# How do I use a PostgreSQL function that returns a table as a CakePHP 3 Model?

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

Using Cake PHP 3.x and we have a PostgreSQL 9.6.3 db.

We make extensive use of PG functions that return tables - for example

```
select * from getStudies(cid,UID, SID);
```

Functions are used for various applications - one of them is more complex filtering of rows from a table - where Cake has difficulty.

One option is to implement the logic as a custom Cake Model method in PHP, but the SQL code and amount of  joins makes it messy in PHP.

We think we should be able to create a Cake Model from the function and then pass the parameters via Cake Model methods but so far - it is unclear how to do that.

This code works but it returns the data without the columns and I have not been able to figure out how to use reflection to get the _columns properties from the Model schema.

```
  public function getStudies($data = array()) {
      $customer_id = $data['customer_id'];
      $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
      $sql = "select * from getStudies($customer_id)";
      $results = $stmt->fetch();
      return $results;   }
```

So - 
Option 1 - figure out how to model a function that returns tables as a cake model

Option 2 - use reflection to get the _columns and merge it with the query result

Thanks

Comment: Is there an actual table with the columns that `getStudies()` returns, or is this partially or even purely virtual? ie, would the model be able to introspect an actually existing schema? Also where do the `cid`, `UID` and `SID` parameters stem from (ie where are they being defined on application level)?

Comment: getStudies returns an actual table (or logical view) - the same Cake Model of the public function.

The parameters are passed to the Model function from a Controller function like this:


    $v = $this->Studies->getStudies( ['customer_id' => 69]);

Comment: In the meantime - I figured out how to get the columns from the Table schema INSIDE a Cake 3.x model:

      $studies = TableRegistry::get('Vstudies');
      $columns = $studies->schema()->columns();

Undocumented but works

Comment: It should be documented in the API docs, it's safe to use ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned in the comments, the schema columns details can be accessed via its `columns()` method. You could process the results manually using the schema information, or use the function as the source, just like in your example.

The query builders `from()` method supports raw SQL as well as expressions, so you can basically add whatever you like, however expressions will be wrapped in parentheses, which will be invalid SQL in case of a function call, so you'd have to go with raw SQL, and bindings (please ***never*** inject (user)data into queries directly):

```php
public function getStudies($customerId)
{
    return $this
        ->find()
        ->from([
            $this->alias() => 'getStudies(:customerId)'
        ])
        ->bind(':customerId', $customerId, 'integer');
}
```

That should generate a query similar to

```sql
SELECT
    Alias.column1, Alias.column2, ...
FROM
    getStudies(:customerId) Alias
```

Comment: Good answer - I was not familiar with $this->alias() => 'getStudies(:customerId)' construct.   Cool.